# Error al enviar UIImage en segue entre dos UIViewController

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Tengo dos UIViewController
En el UIImageView del primer UIViewController cargo una imagen desde la biblioteca. Después con un botón llamado btnContinue intento pasar por medio de un Segue llamado "ChangeView" la imagen dentro del UIImageView a otro UIImageView que se almacena en el segundo UIViewController. A pesar que no me da error alguno, no carga la imagen. El nombre del Segue está bien asignado, ya lo he revisado. La imagen se carga correctamente al escogerla de la biblioteca.

A continuación el código del Segue en el primer UIViewController:

```
///Botón Cotinuar manda al siguiente viewController
@IBAction func btnContinue(_ sender: Any) {
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "ChangeView", sender: self)

}

///Acción Cambiar de vistas a partir de un segue
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if (segue.identifier == "ChangeView") {
        let SecondViewController : SecondViewController = segue.destination as! SecondViewController
        //let meme: UIImage? = imgLogo.image!
        SecondViewController.img = self.imgLogo.image!
    }
}
```

El código del segundo UIViewController:

```
class SecondViewController: UIViewController {

    var img: UIImage?
    @IBOutlet var mainImage: UIImageView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        mainImage.image = img
    }
}
```

Espero me puedan ayudar! Saludos

Answer (score 1):

te recomiendo usar una función estática:

```
   static func push(navigation: UInavigationController, image: UIImage) {
         let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name:"myStoryBoard", bundle: nil)
         guard let vc = story.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "viewControllerId") as? ViewController else { return }
         vc.image = image
         navigation.pushToViewController(vc, animated: true)

   }
```

y en tu acción solo colocas:

```
      guard let navigation = navigationController else { return }
        SecondViewController.push(navigation: navigation, image: imgLogo.image!)
```

es algo similar a lo que estas haciendo pero usando únicamente código sin necesidad de mandar llamar un segue, y te evitas estar usando de mas el storyboard..

parece que en esta funcion algo anda mal.... intenta con algo así...

```
 override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
      if (segue.identifier == "ChangeView") {
           let secondView = segue.destination as! SecondViewController
   secondView.img = self.imgLogo.image!
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

¿Pudiera ser el nombre del view controller?

Intenta nombrando diferente al view controller.

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if (segue.identifier == "ChangeView") {
        if let vc = segue.destination as? SecondViewController {
            vc.img = self.imgLogo.image!
        }
    }
}
```

Si no funciona, intenta poner un breakpoint en esta linea. Para verificar que la imagen exista.

```
vc.img = self.imgLogo.image!
```

E imprime el valor de imgLogo en la consola.

```
po self.imgLogo.image!
```

Answer (score 0):

Suponiendo que lo relacionado al segue esté bien (identifier, tipo, ...) tal vez el problema puede estar relacionado al momento de declarar la variable que contiene al nuevo controller.

Recuerda que es recomendable declarar las variables **siempre** en minúscula, con el fin de diferenciar a estas de las clases y evitar errores y/o confusiones en tu proyecto. Puedes usar alguna nomenclatura como CamelCase, Snake, entre otras...

Intenta cambiar tu código por este.

```
if (segue.identifier == "ChangeView") {
    let controller = segue.destination as! SecondViewController
    controller.img = self.imgLogo.image
}
```

Por otro lado, al momento de hacer el `performSegue` no es obligatorio pasar un dato al parámetro sender. Se suele enviar datos por aquí si es que se piensa usar en el método `prepare`.

```
/// En el parámetro sender, cambiar self por nil
self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "ChangeView", sender: self)
```